# Can I sell and distribute my software using OpenJDK without having to release my code?

Tags: licensing, commercial, gpl-2, redistribution

We develop a software for commercial use and sell it to customers. The software is a web based software that requires Oracle JDK for running (JRE). We are considering moving to OpenJDK because our customers are not interested in paying licenses to Oracle. We would like then to use OpenJDK for running the application and provided that we will not be changing any code we are not sure if the GPLv2 from OpenJDK means also that we would have to be able to show our code if requested to do so.

Can we distribute our software without a worry that we would have to deliver our source code or publish our code?

I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bundling JetBrains OpenJDK in closed source software](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6422/bundling-jetbrains-openjdk-in-closed-source-software). The answer is the same irrespective of which OpenJDK variant you use. It is not under GPL but GPL + Classpath Exception, and that makes all the difference. The GPL is scoped to the JDK and does not affect your code.

Answer (score 3):

```
Oracle makes the OpenJDK source code available under an open-source licensing model.
 It's both gratis, and free (as in freedom) software.
```

Quote from the FAQ for OpenJDK(https://openjdk.java.net/faq/).

```
As a special exception, the copyright holders of this library give you permission to link
 this library with independent modules to produce an executable, regardless of the 
license terms of these independent modules, and to copy and distribute the resulting 
executable under terms of your choice, provided that you also meet, for each linked 
independent module, the terms and conditions of the license of that module. An 
independent module is a module which is not derived from or based on this library.
```

Another quote, from the license(http://openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html) & [Chris Lercher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291741/chris-lercher)